# Javascript: Weird error when working with JS Objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, interact.js

So I've been encountering this error quite a bit lately and it looks like this...

> Main.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'CurrParent' of
>   undefined

And basically I have a couple draggable elements all of which have an attribute called "c_index" which is set to an integer, and what i'm doing with them is using them in another file which is going to act as some sort of a metadata file, and that's where the problem is: I'm storing the "c_index" of the element currently being dragged in a var called CI it looks like this:

```
var CI = event.relatedTarget.getAttribute("c_index");
```

and i'm using it like this:

```
Meta.elements.CI.CurrParent = 'workspace';
```

and the object that i'm trying to save into looks like this without editing:

```
var Meta = { 
    elements : { 
    } 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)
*p.s: I'm using a framework called [interact.js](http://interactjs.io/)*

Comment: That's not "weird".  It just means that `Math.elements.CI` is `undefined`.

Comment: Your `var CI = ...` code won't magically produce a `CI` property on `Meta.elements`. You'd want `Meta.elements.CI = event.relatedTarget.getAttribute("c_index");`. But note that that property will have a primitive string as a value. Setting a property on that primitive string later (`Meta.elements.CI.CurrParent = ...`) is a long-winded no-op (it won't be kept). It would temporarily create a string object, set the property on the string object, and then throw the string object away, with no effect at all on `Meta.elements.CI`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you almost got it but i want it to create a new child object that is called whatever value CI outputs that I can then write into.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean there...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No problem, I understand my wording is all over the place, what i wanted to say is, I have a file, which by default has two nested objects the outer one being called _Meta_ and the inner one being called _elements_, what i want to do is dynamically create another object called _l1_ (which corresponds to the c-index in this case) inside of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment on the question:

> ...what i want to do is dynamically create another object called l1 (which corresponds to the c-index in this case) inside of elements

If I'm understanding you correctly, you'd want to use the value of `c_index` as the property name, via brackets notation. If you want that object to have a `CurrParent` property with the value `"workspace"`, you can initialize that at the same time:

```
var ci = event.relatedTarget.getAttribute("c_index");
Meta.elements[ci] = {CurrParent: "workspace"};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you really helped me out in the long run!